# How do I update a line already existing in JTextPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, document, jtextpane

I would like to add a few lines to JTextPane, such as Joseph Red, Clarita Red, Bob Red, then later I would like to update both the name and color of a particular line, such as, I would like to change Joseph Red to Rudo Blue, or Bob Red to Molly Blue. Is there a way to do so? I wanted to record each line whenever adding a line to JTextPane and reference that particular line to update later on, but could not think of a way.

```
String color = "Red";
JTextPane textPanel = new JTextPane();

public void addToTextPane(String name) throws BadLocationException //Add each line to JTextPane
{
    document = (StyledDocument) textPanel.getDocument();
    document.insertString(document.getLength(), name + "" + color, null);
    document.insertString(document.getLength(), "\n", null);
}
```

I am attempting to do something like the following (Update name and color of that a particular line that's already in the JTextPane):

```
if(...){ 
    status = "Blue";
    try
    {
        addTextPane("Jospeh"); //If I do this, it would not update the already exiting line and
                               //simply just add a new line with the name 'Joseph' and color 'Blue'
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could search the `Document` and replace matches of the existing word...

Comment: @MadProgrammer A bit lost. Do you mind showing example based on mine?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you help me out please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A `for-loop` in combination with `Document#getText`, `Document#remove` `Document#insertString` should do the trick...

[image: Text]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextPane textPane;
        private String fruit[] = {"Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Kiwis"};
        private int index;

        public TestPane() {

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(64);
            text.append("Bananas in pajamas are coming down the stairs\n").
                            append("Bananas in pajamas are coming down in pairs\n").
                            append("Bananas in pajamas are chasing teddy bears\n").
                            append("Cause on tuesdays they try to catch their man-o-wears");

            textPane = new JTextPane();
            textPane.setText(text.toString());
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Update");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    index++;
                    String find = fruit[(index - 1) % fruit.length];
                    String replace = fruit[index % fruit.length];
                    System.out.println("Find: " + find);
                    System.out.println("Replace: " + replace);

                    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();

                    try {
                        for (int pos = 0; pos < doc.getLength() - find.length(); pos++) {

                            String text = doc.getText(pos, find.length());
                            if (find.equals(text)) {
                                doc.remove(pos, find.length());
                                doc.insertString(pos, replace, null);
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (BadLocationException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1 but no need to remove/insert. setCharacterAttributes() is enough

Comment: @StanislavL I took the question to mean the op wanted to replace text, not the attributes, but what do I know :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you please show with the my code integrated? I can't seem to apply it to mine.